# Predictive time modeling for chart

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts, statistics, prediction

I am using highcharts to plot the company revenue on a daily basis on a line chart. I am looking to predict the next five weeks of revenue over the holiday season, for example --

[image]

Is there a plugin for highcharts that does this? Or, is there an open-source library that can be plugged in (ideally in python) that can be used to predict the next weeks of revenue for this?

Update:

The following two modules seem like good starting places:

- [TA Lib](http://ta-lib.org/index.html)
- [Statsmodles](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are dealing with time-series-analysis and prediction. You could look at the Python library [Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) which offers ARMA and ARIMA models straight out of the box.

Comment: thank you very much that seems exactly what I'm looking for. Is this also available in java?

Comment: I dont know. I do all of my analysis in Python, R or MatLab (sporadically). Maybe check this thread for your Java question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/which-library-shall-i-use-for-time-series-analysis-in-java

Comment: Thanks -- here is what seems like a great module for a lot of stats: http://ta-lib.org/index.html.

Comment: Please keep in mind that is a library for *technical analysis* (something used in stock markets) and not the broader *time-series analysis*. Technical analysis is very much based on behavioural analysis and uses 'resistance levels' etc. It is also in general not used for forecasting but more for predicting resistance levels within the next ticks/steps. Time series analysis focuses more on patterns within the time-series (seasonality) and therefore also on prediction.